# Is this necessary to open and close database connection every time if i want to write data from database to .txt file one time in minute?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I want to create a Windows Service in c# (VS). This service will write (rewrite) data from database to .txt file. Do I need open and close connection with database every minute, or I can open it only one time at the beginning service and close connection at the stopping service? I use mssql.

Comment: no.. you dont have to.. its a choice

Comment: Yes, you should not even open/close it once a minute but even if you needed to use this method every second. The reason is, by default the connection-pooling will ensure that not always a real database connection is openend but that an available(not openend) will be used. Therefore it's also important to always close it. So best practice is to not hold a glocal connection object(especially if it's static) but create,open and close it in the method, best by using the `using`-statement.

Comment: I wonder why this question got closed by one that asks for Oracle(this is MSSQL) if OP can use a static connection. This question isn't about static connections but about if a connection must be openend and closed.